JS Class methods scope - in Playwright
I use Playwright JS for automation using VSCODE.
Used Page Obj method to support multiple page/component in application & also test required multiple webpage to be opened so used constructor to assign page
In VSCode , intellisense for class methods is working only in beforeEach block where constructor is invoked. In test block intellisence is not working, pressing ctrl+click on method name pop-ups as "any" , its not showing method defination.
I am missing some config, please suggest me what I missing here
In page1.js
class page1Class {
    constructor(page){
             this.page=page;
     }
     async func1(){
          console.log("This is function1");
     }
}
module.exports = page1Class ;

In page2.js
export default  class page2Class extends page1Class  {
    constructor(page){
             super(page);
             this.page=page;
     }
     async page2func2(){
          console.log("This is function2 PAGE 2");
     }
}
module.exports = page2Class ;

In test files test.spec.js
import page2Class from "../../../pages/page2.js";
let webpage;

test.beforeEach(async({context}) =>{
    webpage= new page2Class (await context.newPage());
    await webpage.page2func2();
    await webpage.func1();
});

//Test works fine , but in VSCODE I cannot navigate to function definition (using ctrl+click) , its popsup as any 
test("test", async() =>{
    await webpage.page2func2();
    await webpage.func1();
}); 

In VSCODE in beforeEach block using ctrl+click navigates to function defination, but I cannot navigate to function definition (using ctrl+click) , its popsup as any

This seems like an Intellisense limitation, it can't figure out that inside test() the beforeEach() assignment has taken place so the type of webpage is page2Class.

Thanks @Barmar,  Is there any extensions in VSCODE to support Intellisense ? I tried few but no luck

I don't understand the question. You're already using Intellisense in VSCode.

@Barmar the questioner doesn’t seem to be a native English speaker. I think the question should have been: "Is there any extension in VSCODE to provide this intellisense?" To answer that question I would say; "You don’t need an extension iff the library from which test() comes from provides declaration files that VSCode can use".

Sounds like you need to tell vscode about the type of the variable where it cannot infer it by itself. In TypeScript, let webpage: Page2Class;, in JavaScript with JsDoc, /** @type{Page2Class} */ let webpage;.

using constructor overload with arg seems to be working , not sure if this acceptable   import page2Class from "../../../pages/page2.js";
let webpage;
webpage =new page2Class (); //without arg
test.beforeEach(async({context}) =>{
webpage= new page2Class (await context.newPage());
await webpage.page2func2();
await webpage.func1();
});
//Test works fine , but in VSCODE I cannot navigate to function definition (using ctrl+click) , its popsup as any
test("test", async() =>{
await webpage.page2func2();
await webpage.func1();
});
